# Communication Between two microservices using ASP.Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two Microservices. First Service for Customers and Second service for Invoice Service.

In Invoice MicroService, I will save only CustomerId. Using this CustomerId, I would like to retrieve all the related data for Customer Microservice. But i don't know to communicate async.

Any please get me some ideas.

Comment: Your communication will be inside a service method (Controller - Service pattern) right? You can make that async and communicate to the other service - which will be most likely an http call, or gRPC if you're using that.

Answer (score 7):

What you are proposing - specifically one service making a direct HTTP call to another - is called [tight coupling](https://nordicapis.com/the-difference-between-tight-coupling-and-loose-coupling/) between services and is an antipattern in Microservices.  It essentially turns your application into a [distributed monolith](https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith/) - it should be avoided.

One example (there are many options) on how to properly do this asynchronously and with good, clean loose-coupled boundaries would be as follows:

- Your system leverages a [message bus](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html) (I like AMQP, but there are other options)
- When a customer is created, your `Customers Service` generates a `customer_created` event
- Your `Invoicing Service` subscribes to these events and, when received, makes necessary internal `customer_id` updates (this is keeping its local data store updated - [eventual consistency](https://solace.com/blog/eventual-consistency-in-microservices/#:%7E:text=eventually.,tasks%20fall%20through%20the%20cracks.))
- When your `Invoicing Service` creates an invoice that requires information from the `Customers Service`, it generates a `cust_invoice_pending` event
- Your `Customers Service` subscribes to this event, and when it sees one, it generates a new message like `invoice_customer_detail_push` on the bus (note, I'd use  an `invoice_id` in the payload of this message to tie them together)
- Your `Invoicing Service` subscribes to and sees this data it needs which allows it to populate the rest of the invoice

It may seem like a lot of extra work and complexity, and indeed it is.  This is the "hard" part of successful microservices architecture.  It takes more discipline and planning up front, but here are the advantages - in this simple case - of the resulting solution versus the distributed monolith you've proposed:

- You could swap out your `Invoicing Service` or `Customers Service` with something completely different without ever touching the code in the other service
- You've abstracted away concerns related to authz for both services - they share the Messaging Bus and so long as they can both get to/from that, neither knows about the other
- You can allow future services to monitor and interact with this business process (creating and detailing an invoice) without ever changing code in these two services
- If one of the two services goes down, the other service continues to be fully responsive and any work waiting on the down service to come back online automatically gets queued - it persists outside the calling/receiving service

So, if the benefits are worth the tradeoffs in your case, have at it.  But, any time you see two "microservices" communicating directly, it's likely you've lost sight a bit of coupling and need to re-examine how information flows through your system.